# Передать двумерный массив из html формы в php

Tags: php, html

Нужно передать двумерный массив из html формы в php, хочу сделать максимально простую форму в одну строку, но либо неправильно реализовал, либо не могу понять в каком формате заполнять форму. Помогите разобраться.

В html: `<br>Array[ ][ ] = <input type="text" name="array[]">`

В php: `$arrXX = $_POST['array'];`

Нужно чтобы можно было ввести любой двумерный массив в форму, а не какой-то конкретной размерности, поэтому не хочу заморачиваться с формой, массивы будут вводиться только "квадратные".

Размерность N тоже ввожу через форму, но с ней проблем нет, т.к. это одно число: `$n = ($_POST['n']) - 1;`

Возможно, с помощью explode() и циклов как-то делить всё, но не могу понять как это работает именно для двумерного массива.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1366752/191482  --- может задавать вопрос каждые 10 минут, чтобы  прям наверняка ответили?

Comment: "чтобы можно было ввести любой двумерный массив в форму, а не какой-то конкретной размерности" --- ты сам понял что написал? двумерный массив - это массив конкретной размерности

Comment: сам я понял, что речь идёт о другой размерности - количество строк и столбцов, если так понятнее. на вводе будут квадратные матрицы

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался:

```
$arrXX = explode("|",$_POST['array']);
```

Строка, введённая в форму, делится на одномерный массив по символам " | "

```
foreach ($arrXX as $key => $val) {
  $val = trim ($val, '|');
```

Символы " | " удаляются

```
  $arrXX[$key] = explode (',', $val);
}
```

Каждый эл-т одномерного массива делится на ещё один массив по символу " , ", получается двумерный массив.

```
$arrXX = explode("|",$_POST['array']);
foreach ($arrXX as $key => $val) {
  $val = trim ($val, '|');
  $arrXX[$key] = explode (',', $val);
}
```